# List all Objects in DigitalOcean Bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to list all of the objects in a bucket on my digital ocean space. Here is my code as of now.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=region_name, endpoint_url=endpoint_url, aws_access_key_id=key, aws_secret_access_key=secret)

bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

for object in bucket.objects.all():
    print(object)
```

Raises the following Exception

```
NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the ListObjects operation: Unknown
```

Any ideas on what could be going wrong or what I need to add. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any syntax or semantical issue with your code. You might be facing issue due to If the path to the **object contains any spaces** or the **object name with any special characters or URL-encoded characters**.

Please refer [troubleshoot the 404 "NoSuchKey" error](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/404-error-nosuchkey-s3/) document from AWS. I would suggest to check for last three bullet items from this document.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the endpoint url I was using for Digital Ocean was containing the bucket name

Removing the bucket name from the endpoint made it work

ex:

Was not working with this url:

`https://some-bucket-name.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com`

This endpoint url worked:

`https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com`